# On some pages ' is not being rendered

Tags: jsp, jstl

On a .jsp file a single quote character : I’m is not being rendered correctly. Instead on Chrome I'm seeing â€™ . Does this mean special characters need to be encoded ? On some .jsp files the single quote character is being rendered correctly but no encoding is occuring.

How can I render a single quote character on a jsp page using/not using jstl ?

Comment: What charset is being sent with the HTTP response? I'd expect to see `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` in a normal scenario.

Comment: @Chris P im not seeing same character on Chrome for this question

Comment: I don't follow. Can you check what charset is being sent?

Comment: @Chris P the response header is Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 so I think that should be Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: @Chris Once I changed the response type to Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 the character displayed correctly, if you put your comment into an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the `Content-Type` HTTP header is setting the charset to `UTF-8`.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

use ascii char for this like `'` ==> `&#39;`
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm